# Difference between `rpy2.robjects.r` and `rpy2.robjects.globalenv`

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I was trying out rpy2 to call R code from python. While trying out some code, I realized that I can define an R function usin `rpy2.robjects.r()` (Notice `()` instead of `[]`, I am calling `r`). Function defined this way can be indexed on both `rpy2.robjects.r` and `rpy2.robjects.globalenv`. However this does not seem to be the case with `pi`. I can do `rpy2.robjects.r['pi']` but I cannot do `rpy2.robjects.globalenv['pi']`:

```
robjects.r("""
    f <- function(){
        print("Hello World!!!")
    }
""")

#function f is defined using rpy2.robjects.r() and can be 
#accessed using rpy2.robjects.globalenv[]
#(as well as using rpy2.robjects.r[])

f = robjects.globalenv["f"]
print(f())      #Hello World!!!

#pi which can be accessed as rpy2.robjects.r[] cannot be 
#accessed as rpy2.robjects.globalenv[]

print(robjects.r['pi'])             #3.141593
print(robjects.globalenv['pi'])     #Error: object 'pi' not found
```

Why is it so?

Answer (score 1):

The rpy2 object `r` is meant to represent "R" running embedded. You can pass it a string in a call (e.g., `r("1+2")`) and that string will be evaluated as R code and the output returned.

On the other hand, `globalenv` is the R "environment" `.Globalenv`. That's basically where objects go when you declare them in an R terminal. R code may make this clearer:

```
x <- 1
# get "x" back, the less-easy way
get("x", .GlobalEnv)
```

When doing `pi` in an R console, the symbol will be searched first in the .GlobalEnv, and if not found the rest of the "search path" (the loaded libraries) will be searched. `pi` is in the R package "base", IIRC.

```
pi # returns 3.14...
pi <- "abc"
pi # return "abc"
```

Comment: *"The rpy2 object `r` is meant to represent "R" running embedded."* So its technically is even bigger scope than `robjects.globalenv`? Is this the same  behavior in plain R? I guess in plain R, all things gets evaluated against `Globalenv` when all local scopes fail. So is `robjects.r` in rpy2 like sourcing the package and then referencing inside it?

Comment: Did you check the documentation ? ( http://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/introduction.html#the-r-instance , http://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/robjects_rinstance.html , http://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/robjects_environments.html )